# Why context2d.backingStorePixelRatio deprecated?

Tags: canvas, dart, html5-canvas

According to Paul Lewis's article, [*High DPI Canvas*](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/hidpi/): You need to take into account the `context.backingStorePixelRatio` to solve blurring issues.

If this property was deprecated, will dart take care of the blur issue on high definition device?

Comment: Anyone from dart team knows this?

Comment: This question makes no sense: `backingStorePixelRatio` isn't even mentioned in the article linked to.

Comment: @Will the article and the question is at least 7 years old. I guess it got updated.

Comment: @KrisztiánBalla Yes, I came to the same conclusion after I wrote that comment. If true, I find it *very* poor form to fundamentally change a published article without including *any* indication that the article was changed. Especially one that was referenced as often as that one apparently was. I see that as a complete lack of integrity.

Comment: BTW, even though I can empirically confirm that the accepted answer below is correct, I find it fairly amusing that it involves zero explanation of the difference between `backingStorePixelRatio` and `devicePixelRatio`. Worse, nobody on the internet seems to have any idea why `backingStorePixelRatio` ever needed to exist in addition to `devicePixelRatio`, when that changed, or why that changed. Every seems to be like "Oh, hey, just write these 2 lines of code and you're good! Bye!"

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I thought the exact same thing and as far as the [Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=277205) tells:

> Yes, so the article was written back when Safari had a backing store
>   ratio of 2. It's always been 1 in Chrome.
>
> As you say the approach for dealing with this is:
>
> `canvas.width = width * window.devicePixelRatio;`
>   `canvas.height = height * window.devicePixelRatio;`
>
> `canvas.style.width = width + 'px';`
>   `canvas.style.height = height + 'px';`
>
> Where `width` and `height` are however you want them (probably
>   window.innerWidth & innerHeight for full viewport shenanigans.)
>
> Then you just need to adjust for the fact that you upscaled the canvas
>   with:
>
> `ctx.scale(window.devicePixelRatio, window.devicePixelRatio);`

So there you have your solution.